# I don't smoke or/and take

Tags: conjunctions

Can "and" be used instead of "or"?

"I don't take antibiotics or/and smoke."
Or in a similar sentence "I don't smoke or drink alcohol."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can say "I don't smoke and drink alcohol", but this would mean that you don't do them both at the same time or on the same occasion.  So if anything, it would tend to suggest that you do both of them, just not at the same time.

"Don't drink and drive" means "don't drink while under the influence of alcohol".

"I don't take antibiotics and smoke" means that you don't smoke when taking antibiotics.

Comment: Not I mean I don't drink alcohol or smoke and I don't smoke or take antibiotics. So and and  or aren't interchangeable.

Comment: No, they're not interchangeable.  To say that you don't drink and you don't smoke, either, you say "I don't drink or smoke" (or you could say "I neither drink nor smoke", but that sounds rather formal).